# I cannot pass data from controller to a view in Sencha Touch 2.4

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, senchatouch-2.4

I have tried some different things but I was unable to pass data from controller to view (to a component inside a container).

Here I have the view [ServisDetail.js](https://gist.github.com/ilhanyumer/1d0a2229d1f075519724#file-servisdetail-js):

```
Ext.define('Asistan.view.ServisDetail', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'servisDetail',
    config: {
        layout: 'fit',
        items : [
            {
                xclass : 'Asistan.view.ServisToolbar'
            },
            {
                // "data: {}" is needed to work. I try to pass data from controller to here
                xtype: 'component',
                tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate','{URUN_CIHAZ_ADI} jkjk')
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

And here is my controller [Servis.js](https://gist.github.com/ilhanyumer/1d0a2229d1f075519724#file-servis-js) which I <del>think</del> thought that it should work. But it doesn't pass the data:

```
Ext.define('Asistan.controller.Servis', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        refs: {
            servis: 'servisNavigationView servisContainer list',
        },
        control: {
            servis: {
                itemdoubletap: 'showServis'
            }
        }
    },
    showServis: function(item, index, e, eOpts) {
        this.servis = Ext.widget('servisDetail');
        this.servis.config.items[1].data = eOpts.data; // <- Here! It doesn't work. console.log shows that the data is there but in the browser the data doesn't show up.
        console.log(this.servis.config.items[1].data); // I can see my data here, right before the push
        item.up('servisNavigationView').push(this.servis);
    }
});
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item with `tpl` should have an `id`.

```
{
    id: 'itemWithTpl', // <- here
    xtype: 'component',
    tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate','{URUN_CIHAZ_ADI} jkjk')
}
```

And the controller:

```
showServis: function(item, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
    this.servis = Ext.widget('servisDetail');
    item.up('servisNavigationView').push(this.servis);
    Ext.getCmp('itemWithTpl').setData(record.data); // <- here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
showServis: function(item, index, e, eOpts) {
    this.servis = Ext.widget('servisDetail');
    this.servis.setData(eOpts.data);  // setData applies the data to the container template.
    item.up('servisNavigationView').push(this.servis);
}
```

Comment: Your code sends the data to the container, not to the component with `tpl`.

Comment: You should avoid using Ext.getCmp() in a Sencha Touch app. You will run into problems if you have multiple instances of your component in your page. Use Ext.ComponentQuery methods instead.

Comment: I would prefer to use itemId instead of id, so that you can destroy views and recreate them.